# Angular 4: Restore localstorage when user press backbutton

Tags: angular

I have a component that manages a list of elements. The user can filter all entries (via three checkboxes). It is possible to click on an element and jump to the second component. This component displays the appropriate details.

The second component is switched to the second component via the function

```
[routerLink]="..."
```

When filtering in the first component, I save all filter options and the results of the list to localstorage.

Now I want to restore the localstorage when the user presses the back button. How can I check in the first component which action the user initiated on the second component?

The URL to the first component looks like this:
http://localhost:4200/regulation

The URL to the secound component looks like this:
http://localhost:4200/regulation/1234566

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy. You can save an array by stringify it with JSON, cause localStorage only accept **strings**.

Here is an example that use **this.filtering** as your filtered array and set it in the localStorage:

```
localStorage.removeItem('filtering');
localStorage.setItem('filtering', JSON.stringify(this.filtering));
```

It's getting removed to remove the last array and to **replace** it.

After you come back from componet 2 you can simply load it again with a JSON parser:

```
this.filtering = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('filtering'));
```

And the last trick if you hit refresh(f5) the data will be the same cause it comes out the localStorage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I said it wrong. I have already filled the storage and when I jump back to component 1 the data is loaded. Bit if I am in component 1 and press F5, the storage should be emptied.

Comment: @Paddy On **ngOnInit** you can do `localStorage.removeItem('filtering');` then it's emptied.

Comment: But when i am an the second component (url: http://localhost:4200/regulation/1234566) und i press the back button to go back to component one (url: http://localhost:4200/regulation), i don´t want to delete the cache. Only when i am on component one and i press refresh. Do you know what i mean? When i do localStorage.removeItem('filtering'); in ngOnInit, the storage will also be removed when i go back from component two or not?

Comment: @Paddy Try something with `this.refresh = true` by default and make it false if back. Based on this you remove it or not.